Self-Attentionのヒートマップが上手く出力されない
実現したいこととして、Self-Attentionから得られた重みであるAttention Weightの可視化結果を正しく出力したい。
入力は動画データをI3Dに適用した特徴マップの0次元目にバッチサイズ30を設定したもの(30, 64, 1024)で、1次元目はフレーム数、2次元目は次元の大きさです。
正常映像と異常映像を同時入力するため、フレーム数の次元はtorch.catで結合しています。
検証時は正常と異常を別で入力するのでtorch.catで結合していません。
Attention Weightは検証時のみ、呼び出してヒートマップで保存するように設定してます。
ネットワークの大枠は下記記載URLのlearner.py以外を採用しました。
https://github.com/seominseok0429/Real-world-Anomaly-Detection-in-Surveillance-Videos-pytorch
Self-Attentionのネットワークは下記記載URLのVideoClassifierクラスから持ってきました。
https://github.com/yaegasikk/attention_anomaly_detector/blob/main/network/video_classifier.py
問題としては、AUCは高く(0.81)、Loss(0.27)も下がっているのにも関わらず、Attention Weightのヒートマップが全て同じ値になっていることです。
検証データは290あるのですが、全て添付画像のようになってしまいます。
各フレームで動きが無い箇所ほど値が低く（黒く）動きがある箇所ほど値が高く（白く）なるのを期待していました。
AUCとLossが問題ないので、原因が全く分からない状況です。

main.py
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from learner import Learner
from loss import *
# from dataset import *
from dataset import *
import os
from sklearn import metrics
from radam import RAdam
import argparse
from FFC import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from torchinfo import summary
import time
from radam import RAdam

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='PyTorch MIL Training')
parser.add_argument('--lr', default=0.001, type=float, help='learning rate')
parser.add_argument('--w', default=0.0010000000474974513, type=float, help='weight_decay')
parser.add_argument('--modality', default='RGB', type=str, help='modality')
parser.add_argument('--input_dim', default=1024, type=int, help='input_dim')
parser.add_argument('--drop', default=0.3, type=float, help='dropout_rate')
parser.add_argument('--FFC', '-r', action='store_true',help='FFC')
parser.add_argument('--seed',default=9111,type=int,help='random seed')
args = parser.parse_args()


best_auc = 0

normal_train_dataset = Normal_Loader(is_train=1, modality=args.modality)
normal_test_dataset = Normal_Loader(is_train=0, modality=args.modality)

anomaly_train_dataset = Anomaly_Loader(is_train=1, modality=args.modality)
anomaly_test_dataset = Anomaly_Loader(is_train=0, modality=args.modality)

normal_train_loader = DataLoader(normal_train_dataset, batch_size=30, shuffle=False)
normal_test_loader = DataLoader(normal_test_dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=True)

anomaly_train_loader = DataLoader(anomaly_train_dataset, batch_size=30, shuffle=False) 
anomaly_test_loader = DataLoader(anomaly_test_dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=True)

device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

if args.FFC:
    model = Learner(input_dim=args.input_dim, dropout=args.drop).to(device)
else:
    model = Learner(input_dim=args.input_dim, dropout=args.drop).to(device)

optimizer = RAdam(model.parameters())
scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.MultiStepLR(optimizer, milestones=[25, 50])
criterion = MIL
# train_loss_history = []
seed = args.seed
torch.manual_seed(seed) 
np.random.seed(seed)
# torch.cuda.synchronize()

def train(epoch):
    print('\nEpoch: %d' % epoch)
    model.train()
    train_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    torch.cuda.synchronize()

    for batch_idx, (normal_inputs, anomaly_inputs) in enumerate(zip(normal_train_loader, anomaly_train_loader)):
        inputs = torch.cat([anomaly_inputs, normal_inputs], dim=1)
        # print(inputs.shape)
        batch_size = inputs.shape[0]
        inputs = inputs.view(-1, inputs.size(-2), inputs.size(-1)).to(device)
        # inputs = inputs.view(-1, inputs.size(-1)).to(device)
        # print(inputs.shape)
        # print(inputs.shape)
        outputs, attention_weights = model(inputs)
        # print(outputs.shape)
        loss = criterion(outputs, batch_size)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        train_loss += loss.item()
        # torch.cuda.synchronize()
    # train_loss_history.append(train_loss/len(normal_train_loader)) 
    print('loss = ', train_loss/len(normal_train_loader))
    scheduler.step()


def test_abnormal(epoch):
    model.eval()
    global best_auc
    auc = 0
    # all_fpr = np.linspace(0, 1, 150)
    # mean_tpr = 0
    # torch.cuda.synchronize()
    # fpr_tpr_file_path = f'fpr_tpr_epoch_{epoch}.txt'
    # fpr_tpr_file = open(fpr_tpr_file_path, 'w')

    with torch.no_grad():
        for i, (data, data2) in enumerate(zip(anomaly_test_loader, normal_test_loader)):
            inputs, gts, frames = data
            inputs = inputs.view(-1, inputs.size(-2), inputs.size(-1)).to(torch.device('cuda'))
            # inputs = inputs.view(-1, inputs.size(-1)).to(torch.device('cuda'))
            # print(inputs.shape)

            score, attention_weights = model(inputs) #予測スコアのみ計測
            
            # print(score.shape)
            score = score.view(-1, score.size(-1)) #SA-MILの時は必要
            # print(score.shape)
            score = score.cpu().detach().numpy()
            score_list = np.zeros(frames[0])
            step = np.round(np.linspace(0, frames[0]//16, 33))
            
            for j in range(32):
                score_list[int(step[j])*16:(int(step[j+1]))*16] = score[j]
            if epoch == 1:
                for j in range(len(attention_weights)):
                    attention_map = attention_weights[j].cpu().detach().numpy()  # Convert to numpy
                    attention_map = attention_map.transpose()
                    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
                    sns.heatmap(attention_map, cmap="hot", annot=False)
                    plt.title(f"Attention Map for sample {i}, time step {j}")
                    plt.savefig(f'attention_map_sample_{i}_time_{j}.png')
                    plt.close()           

            gt_list = np.zeros(frames[0])
            for k in range(len(gts)//2):
                s = gts[k*2]
                e = min(gts[k*2+1], frames)
                gt_list[s-1:e] = 1
                # print(gt_list)

            inputs2, gts2, frames2 = data2
            inputs2 = inputs2.view(-1, inputs2.size(-2), inputs2.size(-1)).to(torch.device('cuda'))
            # inputs2 = inputs2.view(-1, inputs2.size(-1)).to(torch.device('cuda'))
            score2, attention_weights = model(inputs2)
            score2 = score2.view(-1, score2.size(-1))
            score2 = score2.cpu().detach().numpy()
            score_list2 = np.zeros(frames2[0])
            step2 = np.round(np.linspace(0, frames2[0]//16, 33))

            for kk in range(32):
                score_list2[int(step2[kk])*16:(int(step2[kk+1]))*16] = score2[kk]

            gt_list2 = np.zeros(frames2[0])
            score_list3 = np.concatenate((score_list, score_list2), axis=0)
            gt_list3 = np.concatenate((gt_list, gt_list2), axis=0)

            fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(gt_list3, score_list3, pos_label=1)
            auc += metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
        print('auc = ',auc/140)

        if best_auc < auc/140:
            print('Saving..')
            torch.save(model.state_dict(), './checkpoint/SA-MIL-da1.pth')
            best_auc = auc/140

for epoch in range(0, 20):
    train(epoch)
    test_abnormal(epoch)


print("Best AUC:", best_auc)

learner.py
    import torch
    import torch.nn as nn
    import numpy as np
    import torch.nn.functional as F
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import os
    import seaborn as sns
    
    class Learner(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, input_dim = 1024, dropout = 0.0, attention=True):
            super().__init__()
            self.self_attention = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(input_dim,64),nn.Tanh(),nn.Linear(64,3))
            self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_dim*3,32)
            self.fc2 = nn.Linear(32,1)
            self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
            self.sig = nn.Sigmoid()
            self.return_attention = attention
            self.attention_map_index = 0
    
        def forward(self,x):
            bs,t,f = x.shape
            scores = []
            attention_weights = []
            
            for i in range(t):
                attention_weight = self.dropout(F.softmax(self.self_attention(x[:, i, :].unsqueeze(1)), dim=1))
                attention_weights.append(attention_weight.view(bs, -1))
                # print(attention_weight.shape)
                m = torch.bmm(x[:, i, :].unsqueeze(1).permute(0, 2, 1), attention_weight)
                # print(m.shape)
                x_part = m.view(bs, -1)
                # print(x_part.shape)
                x_part = self.fc1(x_part)
                x_part = self.fc2(x_part)
                x_part = self.sig(x_part)
                # print(x_part.shape)
                scores.append(x_part)
    
            scores = torch.stack(scores, dim=1)
            attention_weights = torch.stack(attention_weights, dim=1)
            # print(scores)
            # print(scores.shape)
            print(attention_weights.shape)
    
            if self.return_attention:
                return scores, attention_weights
            else:
                return scores

loss.py
import torch
    import torch.nn.functional as F
    
    def MIL(y_pred, batch_size, is_transformer=0):
        loss = torch.tensor(0.).cuda()
        loss_intra = torch.tensor(0.).cuda()
        sparsity = torch.tensor(0.).cuda()
        smooth = torch.tensor(0.).cuda()
        if is_transformer==0:
            # print(y_pred.shape)
            y_pred = y_pred.view(batch_size, -1)
            # print(y_pred.shape)
        else:
            y_pred = torch.sigmoid(y_pred)
    
        for i in range(batch_size):
            anomaly_index = torch.randperm(30).cuda()
            normal_index = torch.randperm(30).cuda()
    
            y_anomaly = y_pred[i, :32][anomaly_index]
            # print(y_anomaly.shape)
            y_normal  = y_pred[i, 32:][normal_index]
    
            y_anomaly_max = torch.max(y_anomaly) # anomaly
            # print(y_anomaly_max)
            y_anomaly_min = torch.min(y_anomaly)
    
            y_normal_max = torch.max(y_normal) # normal
            y_normal_min = torch.min(y_normal)
    
            loss += F.relu(1.-y_anomaly_max+y_normal_max)
    
            sparsity += torch.sum(y_anomaly)*0.00008
            smooth += torch.sum((y_pred[i,:31] - y_pred[i,1:32])**2)*0.00008
        loss = (loss+sparsity+smooth)/batch_size
    
        return loss


他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿 をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？
